# Default bootstrap navbar doesn't push content down

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, navigation

Good day everybody,
i am having trouble with my responsive bootstrap menu. If i click the toggle button to get the dropdown menu it doesn't push other content down. It just rolls over the content. I have been thinking about it for the past 3 hours and still haven't figured it out.

This is the HTML code.

```css
    nav{
 width:100%;
    position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right:0;
      height:40px;
    }


    nav .navigatsioon .navbar{
 border-radius:0px;
 background-color:transparent;

    }
    nav .navigatsioon .container-fluid{
 text-align:center;
    }
    nav .navigatsioon .navbar.navbar-default{
 border-color:transparent;

    }
    nav .navigatsioon .navbar-default{

    }
    nav .navigatsioon .navbar-default .navbar-nav a{
 color:white;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 font-weight:bold;
 height:40px;
 padding-top:10px;
 border-bottom:3px solid transparent;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  font-size:15px;
    }
    nav .navigatsioon .navbar-default .navbar-nav a:hover{
 color:white;
 border-bottom:3px solid orange;
    }
    nav .navigatsioon .navbar-default .navbar-nav a.active{
 color:white;
 border-bottom:3px solid orange;
    }

    nav .navigatsioon .navbar-default .navbar-nav a:visited{
 text-decoration:none;
 color:white;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 font-weight:bold;
    }
```

```html
<nav>
    <div class="navigatsioon">
    <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-          target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>

    </div>
    </div>


    <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
       <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="http://www.kopakutt.ee/" class="active">AVALEHT</a></li>
         <li><a href="hinnakiri.php">HINNAKIRI</a></li>
        <li>
          <a href="renditingimused.php">Renditingimused</a>
          
        </li>
         <li><a href="tehnika.php">Tehnika</a></li>
        <li><a href="kontakt.php">KONTAKT</a></li>
      </ul>
      
       
        
        </li>
      </ul>
      </div><!-- /.navigatsioon -->
      </div>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->

    </nav>
```

Comment: can you post your bootstrap css external link?

Comment: <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

I problably got my code from here. https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/
I just took some things out. This code works fine on one other webpage i made but i dont know what seems to be the problem now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `position: absolute; top: 0; right:0; height:40px;` in your css. That's causing the problem--

**see the snippet**

```css
.column {
height:100px;
background-color:black;
}
nav{
 width:100%;  
    }


    nav .navigatsioon .navbar{
 border-radius:0px;
 background-color:transparent;

    }
    nav .navigatsioon .container-fluid{
 text-align:center;
    }
    nav .navigatsioon .navbar.navbar-default{
 border-color:transparent;

    }
    nav .navigatsioon .navbar-default{

    }
    nav .navigatsioon .navbar-default .navbar-nav a{
 color:red;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 font-weight:bold;
 height:40px;
 padding-top:10px;
 border-bottom:3px solid transparent;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  font-size:15px;
    }
    nav .navigatsioon .navbar-default .navbar-nav a:hover{
 color:red;
 border-bottom:3px solid orange;
    }
    nav .navigatsioon .navbar-default .navbar-nav a.active{
 color:red;
 border-bottom:3px solid orange;
    }

    nav .navigatsioon .navbar-default .navbar-nav a:visited{
 text-decoration:none;
 color:blue;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 font-weight:bold;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav>
    <div class="navigatsioon">
    <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
   
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>

    </div>
 


       <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="http://www.kopakutt.ee/" class="active">AVALEHT</a></li>
         <li><a href="hinnakiri.php">HINNAKIRI</a></li>
        <li>
          <a href="renditingimused.php">Renditingimused</a>
          
        </li>
         <li><a href="tehnika.php">Tehnika</a></li>
        <li><a href="kontakt.php">KONTAKT</a></li>
      </ul>
      
       
        
      
      </div><!-- /.navigatsioon -->
    
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->

    </nav>
    <div class="column col-xs-12">
    </div>
```

Comment: I tryed to remove position:absolute; but it didn't help. I also did this @media (max-width: 880px) {
  nav{
    position:relative;
    background-color:black;
  }

Comment: You were right. position: absolute; top: 0; right:0; height:40px; was the problem. Now the code looks like this and it works fine. nav{
position:absolute;
right:0;
margin-top:-360px;
}